# Deleted user but files keep his group?

Tags: ubuntu

I removed a user from my computer. 
Now there's a lot of files that I need to modify that are from the deleted user group.

How can I change ALL file group and owner from that deleted user without having to manually change the group for each file?

Answer (score 10):

Use `find`.

```
find / -gid 510 -exec chgrp staff {} +
```

Comment: Right, except I would suggest `+` instead of `\;` for the exec to reduce the number of invocations. Also, note that this will take a while as it traverses your entire directory tree (which is unavoidable).

Comment: Yep, you're right.